# USB Debugging in VitualBox-hosted Android system

Tags: android, windows, usb, virtualbox

I have set up a virtual machine running an Android 4.4 system on VirtualBox, in a Windows 7 system, for convenience in testing an Android app I am trying to develop. What last remains, is to be able to make the guest Android OS look like it's connected to the host via USB, to be able to use USB Debugging. Is there a way to achieve that?

EDIT: By "convenience" I mean I do not have a good enough physical device at my hands at the moment, and my processor happens not to support VT-x, in which case I could just use an AVD with Android Studio. Therefore, the VirtualBox choice is the next best thing I got, until I get a new device on my hands. What has priority at the moment is to create the app's utility, looks will be taken care of later on.

Comment: Is setting up Android in VirtualBox really more convenient than simply plugging your phone into your PC? All those questions talking about using the emulator or in your case VirtualBox for "convenient" testing always mystify me because they all seem to miss the point of an emulator. You are not supposed to use it as main testing device. Testing on a real device will always be better, quicker and more convenient. More importantly testing on a real device also yields much better results. For example you cannot test the usability of an app by clicking around on a PC.

Comment: You need to hold the phone in your hand and interact with the app just like your users will interact with it. Only then can you get a feel for how well your app works. Googles own advice about the emulator is to use it to test your app on devices which you don't physically own or to supply mock sensor data. Another use-case for the emulator would be to test the app on devices with unrealistically tiny or huge displays so you can be sure that the layout works on any possible device. But that is pretty much as far as I would go, I would never suggest to use an emulator as main testing device.

Comment: I do know that using a real device would be better. However, I do not have a good enough device at the moment, and I don't want to sit there doing nothing until I get one. For starters, I want to create the utility, and that can very easily be achieved in an emulated device. Looks will be polished later on.

Comment: It's unlikely you will be able to.make this appear as USB.  Rather you should use adb over TCP.  A setup which didn't support that would be comparatively useless.

Comment: Well how will I run adb where needed, without connecting to usb? Adb needs to be run by the computer cmd, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Android system is rooted you can install Wifi ADB (or some similar application) through Android Play store and debug over TCP.

The steps can be simply:

- Install Wifi ADB (from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=es)
- Execute and start service (Bettle will go to green)
- Open Command line in Windows 7 machine
- Run the connection command, for example:

  adb connect 192.168.125.232
- Test device connection with

  adb devices
- Enjoy testing your application!

Comment: The Android system is not rooted, so it would be helpful if I could find a solution not involving that, unless it's the only way (all i want is to test the app on a normal android system). On a side note, two non-rooting requiring wifi adb apps I tried, still asked me to connect the device on the PC with a USB, for start.

Comment: And since the system is in a VM and connected to Internet through "Ethernet" or "Mobile Data", I doubt on whether I can "connect" it to some actual wi-fi.

Comment: As Xaver Kapeller said, it is more useful and convenient test apps in a real device. To debug through tcp over ethernet in a non rooted device you must first connect the USB cable, enable tcpip mode and then connect to given port.

Comment: Your VM is almost certainly either already rooted, or trivially rootable.  Chances are adb is listening on TCP out of the box - it wouldn't be very useful otherwise.